# Blaze.renderWithData - how to automatically update template if data changes?

Tags: meteor

I have built a list using Meteor. I do not want the entire list to be reactive, i.e. auto-update when the data changes. However, I do want the title of a list item to update if the data relating to that list item changes. I am inserting the list items using `Blaze.renderWithData`, so how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use two helpers, a non-reactive one which returns the cursor and a reactive one which returns the title. To make something non-reactive, use [Tracker.nonreactive](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_nonreactive), [(related question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197247/how-do-i-make-a-meteor-helper-non-reactive).

In the following contrived example I'm returning a reactive title that includes the cursor count if non-zero while the cursor returned from the helper is non-reactive.

```
subHandle = Meteor.subscribe('mySubscription');

Template.foo.helpers({
  cursor: function(){
    if ( subHandle.ready() ) return Tracker.nonreactive(function() {
      return myCollection.find(query,options);
    });
  }),
  title: function(){
    var nDocs = myCollection.find(query,options).count();
    if ( nDocs ) return "Title (" + nDocs + ")";
    else return "Title";
  }
});
```

**Update:**
Modified to deal with the subscription handle being ready so that the nonreactive function is called for the first time with a ready subscription.

[Here's a Meteorpad with a working example](http://meteorpad.com/pad/g88S4hK8Y2WnBzsJ2/Leaderboard). You can see that the total points updates as you add points to players but the player scores and sort never change.

Comment: @ Michel Floyd Are you suggesting it can't be done when using Blaze.renderWithData ?

Comment: Not at all. These helpers can be on the template that embeds the dynamic template for example. I guess in that case you wouldn't need the `cursor` helper, you would just use `Tracker.nonreactive` to get the data context for your `Blaze.renderWithData()`

Comment: @ Michel Floyd - Would you mind adding and example using Blaze.renderWithData() to the answer you provided?